# How to check if Pandas rows contain any full string or substring of a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a list of strings

```
list_ = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz']
```

And I have a `df` with column `CheckCol`, that I want to check if the values in `CheckCol` contains any of the whole of substring of the list element.

If it does, I want to extract the original value into a new column `NewCol`.

```
CheckCol
'a'
'ab'
'abc'
'abc-de'
```

Into

```
# What I want
CheckCol        NewCol
'a'
'ab'
'abc'           'abc'
'abc-de'       'abc-de'
```

My following codes, however, only recognize the exact full string, but not the substrings I was looking for.

```
df['NewCol'] = np.where(df['CheckCol'].isin(list_), df['CheckCol'], '')
```

And gives

```
# What I get
CheckCol        NewCol
'a'
'ab'
'abc'           'abc'
'abc-de'
```

Edits: Changed `list` to `list_`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the "easiest" implemented solution would be to use a regex-expression. In regex the pipe `|` means or. By doing `'|'.join(yourlist)` we get the substrings we want to check.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list_ = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CheckCol': ['a','ab','abc','abd-def']
})

df['NewCol'] = np.where(df['CheckCol'].str.contains('|'.join(list_)), df['CheckCol'], '')

print(df)

#  CheckCol   NewCol
#0        a         
#1       ab         
#2      abc      abc
#3  abd-def  abd-def
```

---

**NOTE:** Your variable name `list` was changed to `list_`. Try to avoid using the reserved Python namespace.